# Searching for an "id" saved in a list to get all the other fields

Tags: c#, arrays, list, search

I've a list which each index saves a patient with his id, name, age, (...); I'm currently using this code when searching for one:

```
foreach (Paciente patient in pacientes)
{
    if (patient.id == Convert.ToInt32(txtIDP.Text))
    {
        txtNomeP.Text = patient.nome;
        txtIdadeP.Text = Convert.ToString(patient.idade);
        txtMoradaP.Text = patient.morada;
        txtContatoP.Text = patient.contato;
        txtEmailP.Text = patient.email;

        break;
    }
    else
    {
        txtNome.Clear();
        txtIdade.Clear();
        txtMorada.Clear();
        txtNumero.Clear();
        txtEmail.Clear();

        MessageBox.Show(
            "Não existe nenhum paciente com esse ID!", 
            "Error!", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

But I know this is not correct because it will search on the list if it exists and it will automatically show the MessageBox that the id couldn't be found before finding an id. And of course, it will show the error the n times of the array lenght. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: `thisP = pacientes.Where( x=> x.ID == idFin).FirstOrDefault()`  or move the MessageBox outside the loop

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ like this:

```
Paciente patient = pacientes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == Convert.ToInt32(txtIDP.Text));

if (patient == null)
{
    txtNome.Clear();
    txtIdade.Clear();
    txtMorada.Clear();
    txtNumero.Clear();
    txtEmail.Clear();
    MessageBox.Show("Não existe nenhum paciente com esse ID!", "Erro!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
}
else
{
    txtNomeP.Text = patient.nome;
    txtIdadeP.Text = Convert.ToString(patient.idade);
    txtMoradaP.Text = patient.morada;
    txtContatoP.Text = patient.contato;
    txtEmailP.Text = patient.email;                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var found = false;
foreach (Paciente patient in pacientes)
{
    if (patient.id == Convert.ToInt32(txtIDP.Text))
    {
        txtNomeP.Text = patient.nome;
        txtIdadeP.Text = Convert.ToString(patient.idade);
        txtMoradaP.Text = patient.morada;
        txtContatoP.Text = patient.contato;
        txtEmailP.Text = patient.email;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found)
{
    txtNome.Clear();
    txtIdade.Clear();
    txtMorada.Clear();
    txtNumero.Clear();
    txtEmail.Clear();
    MessageBox.Show("Não existe nenhum paciente com esse ID!", "Erro!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: I remembered now about the bool variable, thank you anyway Arghya! :)